# Vector space with Euc. Scalar Product Find Counter Example

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have a Vector space with the regular Euclidian Scalar Product.
A linear mapping F: V-> V

Task is to prove or refute for V $\in \Re $

$$ <v, F(v)> =0 => F(v) = 0 ,\,   \forall v \in V $$

My idea is 
since V has a scalar product, we know

```
<v, v> = 0 => v = 0
```

so if F(v) = v it would be true, but cannot think of a counterexample why it would not necessarily hold for all F's in $ <v, F(v)> $.

Note this is for reals only.

Comment: You might get a hint from examination of what happens when $v=x+y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the dot product is 0 when the vector and its image are orthogonal. Now consider rotations in 2D...